What is the name of an 80s movie featuring a small living ball from space?
I have a vague memory of seeing a small budget kids movie on VHS in the late 80s or early 90s featuring a creature from space that looks like a ball. I'm not sure but it might have been a steel ball or a dark coloured marble. One scene in this movie had a supermarket being taken over by the ball and its counterparts. Which just looked like dozens of these balls rolling down the aisles.
Has anyone seen this movie or know what it is called?
What I remember of this movie has not made it easy to search for given that "space" and "ball" makes search engines think I'm looking for Spaceballs.

I have read about a British movie from 1977 called The Glitterball.

Two boys befriend a stranded alien in the shape of a little silver
ball and help it to return home

When I did a Google 'image search' for The Glitterball, I found some that showed many tiny balls rolling down a supermarket aisle.


Yes this must be it! Thank you!
It's weird what my memory of this scene looked like compared to the still. Much less brown.
